# Windows authentication inside microsoft teams

Tags: windows-authentication, microsoft-teams

I have designed a website to use windows authentication. Everything works as expected. But my recent task was to integrate the site into Microsft Teams. So I have created de manifest and install de app in teams.  So When I enter the  site it is asking for windows credentials and user validated, but after pass the credentials the page doesn t load, it stay in blank. The web site is working succesfully in any web explorer.

Note: I use the Active Directory of my company to validate users (Not Azure AD).

Thanks in advance.

```js
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "id": "276adadb",
    "packageName": "TI_MesaAyuda",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Enzo",
        "websiteUrl": "",
        "privacyUrl": "https://tickets.Prueba.Teams",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://tickets.Prueba.Teams"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Mesa de ayuda TI",
        "full": "Sistema de mesa de ayuda"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Mesa de ayuda de ",
        "full": "Sistema de mesa de ayuda de Megalabs     "
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "Ticket1",
            "name": "Mesa de ayuda",
            "contentUrl": "https://tickets.prueba.teams",
            "websiteUrl": "https://tickets.prueba.teams",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "tickets.prueba.teams",
        "https://tickets.prueba.teams"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Probably you missed out something in manifest. Can you please share your manifest here. Just remove id's and share it here.

Comment: it might be that a domain is missing in the "valid domains" section in the manifest

Comment: I added the manifes, like you ask. I continue with the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT  there is the manifest. Thanks

Comment: you don't use the "https://" prefix in the "Valid domains" section, so just take out that line (it's basically a duplicate). I can't visit the url itself though, so is it a live internet site, or do you have another way to resolve it (e.g. HOSTS file)?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow you are right, I just put de https: for test. Is a live site, I put that url for the example, but the real Url is https://tickets.megalabs.global you can check the site but it will ask you for credentials.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for clarifying. You can remove the website link above if you want to keep it private. Is there a difference in the experience in Teams desktop versus opening Teams in the browser? Also, what are your browser settings? Do users have that site registered in the "Intranet" zone (which would enable it to auto-login)?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow for ur first question: Is the same using desktop or browser version of teams. And yes, in the Intranet the users doesn t need to enter credentials because it takes from windows credentials to login in the app, so they enter automaticly. But when you are out from the Intranet you need to enter credentials and then u are redirect to the site.